# Synonym for "It is easy to acknowledge accuracy to be a very important feature"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

What is an alternative expression for : *"It is easy to acknowledge accuracy to be a very important feature"*.

The word **Accuracy** should remain in the sentence.

In an academic context.

Comment: Especially the first part: **"It is easy"**. I want to change it.

Comment: Accuracy can be immediately identified as a preeminent feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"easy to acknowledge" could be replaced by "obvious", or "clear", or a similar idiom.

For example,

> It's *clear* that accuracy is an important feature.

or,

> It *stands without reason* that accuracy is of utmost importance.

Also I am not sure that "accuracy" should be listed as a feature for anything. Accuracy means something like "without faults". Should "lack of faults" really be described as a feature?

Comment: "stands without reason" or "stands to reason" ? I can only  find the latter in the online references...

Comment: Interesting, I thought it was common. I must yield to the experts on this one...

Answer (score 3):

You could try

> Accuracy is essential.

Three words.

Comment: Depending on context, you could easily add a "therefore" in here to replace "it is easy": "[context] Therefore, accuracy is essential." Other variations: "We acknowledge accuracy as essential." "We easily acknowledge accuracy as essential." _Acknowledge_ is a bit of a weak word and could be replaced: "We have made accuracy essential" or "We make accuracy essential."

Comment: And if you want to sound smart: **accuracy is of the essence**

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is readily acknowledged as a salient feature (characteristic;facet).

Answer (score 2):

> Accuracy is acknowledged as an
>   essential feature

would be a good way of writing it as I think stating it as Robusto said in the above post might be read as you asserting the fact that "accuracy is essential", whereas using "accuracy is acknowledged" seems more like it is a fact acknowledged by a group of people.

Also tenfour mentioned that maybe accuracy shouldn't be described as a feature. I would argue that in some cases accuracy isn't essential, for example when gathering quantitative data rather than qualitative, it might be more important to focus on gathering large amounts of data rather than ensuring 100% accuracy on every piece of data collected.